# Why it says there's error "No resource found that matches" even though it exists?

Tags: android

Error Message

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/rightBehindMenuScroll').
```

**layout/activity_behind_right_simple.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/rightBehindMenuScroll" >

    <LinearLayout style="@style/behindMenuScrollContent"
        android:paddingTop="25dp" >
        <TextView
            style="@style/behindMenuItemTitle"
            android:text="Right" />
        <TextView
            style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
            android:text="Item0" />
        <TextView
            style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
            android:text="Item1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/behind_btn"
            style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
            android:text="BUTTON" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>


    <style name="leftBehindMenuScroll">
        <item name="android:layout_width">240dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/leftbg</item>
    </style>
    <style name="rightBehindMenuScroll">
        <item name="android:layout_width">200dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rightbg</item>
    </style>
    <style name="behindMenuScrollContent">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
        <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="behindMenuItemTitle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
    <style name="behindMenuItemLabel">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: Are you using Studio or Eclipse? The Gradle build system is a bit temperamental when it comes to resources. Try removing the `build/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Thats b'coz you are using styles.xml instead of style.xml.

Try changing referance as follows...

```
 <TextView
            style="@styles/behindMenuItemTitle"
            android:text="Right" />
```

in same way with all other referances of styles.xml file...

Comment: I replaced all `@style` with `@styles` but it still says `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/RightBehindMenuScroll').`

Comment: This answer is wrong. `@styles` is incorrect syntax. The filename `styles.xml` is completely irrelevant and can be anything you want.